# Chrome fails to load TinyMCE in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-chrome

My visual editor in WordPress doesn't work and I figured out that was because my computer doesn't load the full tinymce folder. It only loaded "mce-view.js". In another computer, using Chrome, around 15 js elements were loaded.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: We need more information on your setup. Which version of Chrome? Do you have JavaScript disabled?

Comment: Hi, I have Chrome 44.0.2453.115m - the latest version. I also have JaveScript enabled. The other computer has the exact same settings. I've tried installing Java, disabling Ad Block, enabling NPAPI support but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FIXED IT.

So it turned out to be a conflict between my antivirus setting and WordPress.

I use Symantec Endpoint Protection and it sets my browser to Stealth Mode which makes some websites malfuction. All I need to do was go to Symantec -> Change Settings -> Network Threat Protection ---click on Configure Setting ---> On Firewall tab, **uncheck "Enable Stealth Mode web browsing".**

Good luck finding your solutions.

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Enabling NPAPI in Chrome Version 42 and later
As of Chrome Version 42, an additional configuration step is required to continue using NPAPI plugins.

In your URL bar, enter:
[chrome://flags/#enable-npap](http://chrome://flags/#enable-npap)i 
Click the Enable link for the Enable NPAPI configuration option.
Click the Relaunch button that now appears at the bottom of the configuration page.

Comment: Hi way to many things to wright so just check here [link](http://www.ghacks.net/2015/04/15/chrome-42-blocks-java-silverlight-other-plugins-by-default-now/)